# Create redirect url in facebook using php

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a facebook redirect url like **/fblogin?packgeid=1** in my Codeigniter application

where `packgeid` is a dynamic value like (1,2,3)

I tried `https://localhost/project/fblogin?packgeid={}`  in facebook Valid OAuth Redirect URIs, but receive an error in facebook response like:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use any placeholders or anything like that. If you need to transport any info in your redirect URI via GET parameters, then you would need to enter each any every specific URL explicitly.

The only parameter that is except from this, is the `state` value. Its main purpose is CSRF protection - but you can use it to transport your own values as well. It should not be a purely static or easily guessable value though (that would stop it from being effective as CSRF protection measure) - so maybe combine a random value and your parameter value, encoding it as JSON, or something like that - that would help you to easily take it apart on the receiving end again.

---

But do you even need to actually transport this via the redirect URI? Can you not just put `packgeid=1` into your session, and then have the script decide what it needs to do after the user is redirect back, based on that?

Comment: can you give me a example ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#logindialog has an example, if you scroll down a bit.